# APA Citation Page - problems with issue number and journal names

Tags: style, academic-writing, citations, apa

I have written out an APA citation page. I will attach a link to the page below. I have been told that there is an issue with the way my journal names have been presented and also one issue with one of the issue numbers. I can't see a single problem with any of these things. Can someone please help me out?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vOmUnuoNToaycWkoUTD6YLbcLpi7xtlHJ5Nf01E7tHE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What have you been told is wrong with it? Or did they just tell you it's wrong and leave you guessing?

Comment: The full stop needs to be outside the parenthesis containing the date, e.g. `(1997.)` must be `(1997).`. Other than that I find nothing amiss. You should give issue numbers only if each issue's page numbers begin at 1. If the page numbers of one volume (year) run "across" issues, that is, if issue 1 ends on, say, page 235 and issue 2 begins on page 236, giving the issue number is deprecated (but not outright wrong). In APA one basic rule is to trim away anything unnecessary, both in your writing and in formatting. If the issue number is unnecessary to locate a source, trim it.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close; citations and style guides are clearly on-topic here, as is academic writing. If this gets closed, let's open up a meta thread to discuss why. Perhaps this is being looked at as a proofreading request?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the aforementioned need for the periods/full stops to be after the close parentheses for your dates, your citation for Brunetti needs a colon separating the title from the subtitle. I know it's counterintuitive to put a colon after a question mark but in this case, the question mark isn't being used as punctuation but to faithfully reproduce the formal title.